# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (213,) but got array with shape (210,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, nlp

It seems the input array does not fit the input shape but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Here is how I build the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

#Training and saving the model

hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('buy_model_08152020th.h5', hist)
#print("model is created")
```

And here is the predict class function:

```
def predict_class(sentence):
    global custom_prompt
    # filter below threshold predictions
    p = bag_of_words(sentence, words, show_details=False)
    res = model.predict(np.array([p]))[0]
    error_threshold = 0.90
    results = [[i, r] for i,r in enumerate(res) if r > error_threshold]
    # Sort strength probability
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = [{"intent": "message classification failed"}]
    for r in results:
        return_list.append({"intent": classes[r[0]], "probability": str(r[1])})
    if len(return_list) > 1:      
        result = return_list[1]["intent"]
    if len(return_list) == 1:
        result = return_list[0]["intent"]               
    return result
```

And the bag_of_words_function:

```
def bag_of_words(sentence, words, show_details=True):
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    #bag of words - vocabulary matrix
    bag = [0] * len(words)
    for s in sentence_words:
        for i,word in enumerate(words):
            if word == s:
                bag[i] = 1
                if show_details:
                    print('found in bag: %s' %word)
    return(np.array(bag))
```

Error message:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have
> shape (213,) but got array with shape (210,)

Comment: Can you provide details for  the `bag_of_words` function?

Comment: Just added the bag_of_words function to the question.

Comment: @LucasJacaruso, You have to `pad` your sequences so that the all the sentences will have same number of words. If this doesn't resolve your issue, please share the complete code so that we can reproduce it at our end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, the `input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),)` is `213` while training the model, but you are using the input `p` of `210` while doing the prediction. Suggest you to print the `len` of input to the model(`print len(train_x[0])`) and the `len` of input to prediction(`print len(p)`). They both should be same else this error is thrown.

If the error is still not fixed then kindly share the reproducible code or complete code with required input details.